# How can I access workflow fields and store them in content fields in drupal

Tags: workflows

I have a workflow called custom and it has workflow field called assign user , now i am using this workflow on my content type complaints and it is showing the workflow form in a field called field_workflow_state and in the workflow history it is storing the assigned user , now i want to retreive the assigned user and store it in another field called assigned to . I tried many options but none have worked.

[image]
[image]